# Below java code runs, not sure if this kind of code is allowed by java compiler

Tags: java

Hi I am not sure but below code compiles and runs but below line of code looks weird.

```
public int Integer = new Integer(1);
```

Is this some special syntax?

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public int Integer = new Integer(1);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }   
}
```

Comment: What specifically do you think is wrong with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integer is not a reserved word, so it can be used as an attribute name. So basically `public int Integer` is an attribute called `Integer` using the int primitive.

The Integer attribute will create a new `Integer` object and the java compiler will autoboxing it to the integer primitive. [Give a look here for more details](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

What you did is equivalent to this:

```
Integer Integer = new Integer(1);
```

And is also equivalente to this:

```
int Integer = 1;
```

Comment: Yes I reliased that after I tried to assign new Object() it was not taking it. Thanks